# When I run my lisp code, it says undefined function NIL

Tags: lisp

The task was to Create an XLISP program that simulates the stack implementation of push and pop. Remember, the push and pop of a stack happens only on the top of stack (which is different from a queue)
In this case, we assume that the right most part of your list is the top portion.
Push operation description

1. Ask the user to enter a number
2. Insert the data into your stack
3. 0 or negative number is not allowed. If so, simply print "Invalid Input"
   Pop
   Simply removes the top data from your stack.
   Assumption:
   You have a list called mystack initialized as an empty list.
   Example Run:

> (setq myStack())
> NIL
> (push)

*** When I try to run the code it says that `undefined function NIL`

```
(setq myStack(nil))
> (push)
> (pop)
; PUSH Function
(defun push ()
  (let ((num (read)))
    (if (and (numberp num) (> num 0))
        (setq myStack (append myStack (list num)))
      (print "Invalid Input"))))

; POP Function
(defun pop ()
  (if (null myStack)
      (print "Stack is empty")
    (progn
      (setq myStack (butlast myStack))
      (print myStack))))
```

Comment: Does your XLISP provide macros `defparameter` or `defvar`? And do you really have to manipulate the last element of the list? I think manipulating the first one would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem first of all is

```
(setq myStack (nil))
```

In Common Lisp, one would write it:

```
(defparameter *my-stack* nil)
```

In Common Lisp, there is the equality: `NIL == () == '() == 'NIL`.
What you want is an empty list, which is one of those.
Remember, an empty list `()` or `'()` already contains an implicit `NIL`
as its last `CDR`. Proof:

```
(cdr ())   ;; => NIL
(cdr '())  ;; => NIL
(cdr NIL)  ;; => NIL
(cdr 'NIL) ;; => NIL
```

At least in Common Lisp it is defined like this.

However, in Racket/Scheme this is not defined like this. Therefore, this is not universal to Lisps:

```
$ racket
Welcome to Racket v6.11.

> (cdr NIL)
; NIL: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
; [,bt for context]
> (cdr '())
; cdr: contract violation
;   expected: pair?
;   given: '()
; [,bt for context]
> (cdr ())
; readline-input:4:5: #%app: missing procedure expression;
;  probably originally (), which is an illegal empty application
;   in: (#%app)
; [,bt for context]
> (cdr 'NIL)
; cdr: contract violation
;   expected: pair?
;   given: 'NIL
; [,bt for context]
```

Therefore, in XLISP this must not be ...
However, for all lisps, it will be true that you need `'()` as an empty list.
So at least, your line must be:

```
(setq my-stack '())
```

If you forget the quote `'`, the interpreter/compiler thinks it is a function call and searches the function name `nil` and doesn't find it. Therefore your error.

Later you ask in your `pop` function: `(null my-stack)`. If you start with `'(nil)`, the problem is you don't start with an empty list.
Proof:
In Common Lisp:

```
(null '(nil)) ;;=> nil
```

In Racket:

```
(null? '(nil)) ;;=> #f
```

Why? because your list then contains still and element which has as value `NIL`.
In both languages, you can do:

```
(cdr '(nil)) ;;=> '() <-- Now the list is empty!
```

I would define your `push` und `pop` in Common Lisp:

```
(defparameter *my-stack* '())

(defun my-push (x)
  (setf *my-stack* (cons x *my-stack*))

(defun my-pop ()
  (let ((x (car *my-stack*)))
      (setf *my-stack* (cdr *my-stack*))
      x))
```

As you see I don't append it at the end because this is very inefficient (otherwise one has to traverse the entire list).
In Lisp, one adds at the start by `cons`-ing. And pops from the start by `car`-ing and `cdr`-ing.

Also, your pop doesn't return the pop-ed value.
Actually, your function to behave like the in-built `push` and `pop` in Common Lisp, must be:

```
(defmacro my-push (x lst)
  `(setf ,lst (cons ,x ,lst)))

(defmacro my-pop (lst)
  `(let ((x (car ,lst)))
    (setf ,lst (cdr ,lst))
    x))
```

Usage:

```
(defparameter *stack* '())

(my-push 1 *stack*) ;;=> (1)
(my-push 2 *stack*) ;;=> (2 1)
(my-push 3 *stack*) ;;=> (3 2 1)

*stack* ;;=> (3 2 1)

(my-pop *stack*)    ;;=> 3
(my-pop *stack*)    ;;=> 2
(my-pop *stack*)    ;;=> 1
(my-pop *stack*)    ;;=> NIL
(my-pop *stack*)    ;;=> NIL

;; whether the list is empty or the first element's value is NIL
;; you can check by (length *stack*) => if that is 0, the stack is empty
```

In racket:

```
(define-syntax-rule (push x lst) 
  (set! lst (cons x lst)))

(define-syntax-rule (pop lst) 
  (let ((x (car lst))) 
    (set! lst (cdr lst)) 
    x))
```

Usage:

```
> (define stack '())
> (push 1 stack)
> (push 2 stack)
> (push 3 stack)
> stack
'(3 2 1)
> (pop stack)
3
> (pop stack)
2
> (pop stack)
1
> (pop stack)
; car: contract violation
;   expected: pair?
;   given: '()
; [,bt for context]
```